# How do I turn a pen outline into a single object for gradients? (Inkscape)

Tags: inkscape, gradient, pen-tool

My question is a bit weirdly worded, but I'm sure this is common thing to ask. I inserted an image and traced it with the pen tool, but I didn't do it in one go. I have one part, which itself was done in separate traces, so it's made out of three separate traces, I thought connected the nodes would automatically turn it into a whole shape, but during a gradient, I get this weird pattern where the gradient connect in an a to b fashion of the nodes that were connected, like so.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, what I did was use the node editor tool to move the points where the path end nodes were cusped (I moved them apart) and then held shift while I selected both, then I hit the "Join nodes" button on the tool bar. This connected them back to the original shape and made the gradient solid throughout the path.

[image]